# get the total width of specified elements including there margin and padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ok i have this code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var totalWidth = 0;

    $('.thewidgets').each(function(index) {
        totalWidth += parseInt($(this).width(), 10);
    });

    $('#marginwidgets').css({width: totalWidth});

});
</script>
```

the html

```
<div id="marginwidgets">
 <div class="thewidgets">
  the widgets 1
 </div>
 <div class="thewidgets">
  the widgets 2
 </div>
 <div class="thewidgets">
  the widgets 3
 </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
#marginwidgets
{
margin: 0px auto;
overflow: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
.thewidgets
{
width: 284px
padding: 5px;
margin-left: 10px;
}
.thewidgets:first-child
{
margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```

As you can see in the script, the routine is to get the total width of .thewidgets and then apply the total width of that into the #marginwidgets that should make perfect centralized of #marginwidgets.

but i want the total width of .thewidgets include there margin and there paddings and then apply it into the #marginwidgets but i dont know how to make it, could someone here figure it out how to do it please?

Comment: `totalWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);` No need to parseInt, we know what it returns.

Comment: thank you .. works like charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`outerWidth`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) instead of width, and pass `true` as an argument to include the margins:

```
$(this).outerWidth(true);
```

Also the dimension functions return Numbers as opposed to strings so `parseInt` isnt necessary though you might want to use `Math.floor`, `Math.ceil` or `Math.round`.